# Concurrent signal handling in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, concurrency, signals, sh

It appears that the shell may concurrently execute signal handlers (trap actions) if the shell receives a new signal while being busy with the previous. Here is an example script

```
handler() {
     echo -n '<'
     for i in a b c d e; do echo -n $i; sleep 1; done
     echo -n '>'
}
trap handler USR1
...
```

Which produces the following output

```
<ab<abcd<abcde>e>cde>
^  ^    ^
|  |    |
signal received
```

This behavior breaks complex handlers.

I have found experimentally that atomicity can be achieved through execution in a subshell:

```
trap '(handler)' USR1

<abcde><abcde>
^  ^  ^
|  |  |
signal received
```

And that `foo=$(handler)` is atomical too (in sense that it won't be interrupted by a signal), enabling handlers to change shell's state.

However, the whole issue appears to be linux-specific: bash on Mac OS doesn't interrupt handlers at all. That makes my solution rely on undocumented behavior to overcome undocumented platform-specific behavior. That doesn't sound to be reliable.

I couldn't find any knowledge on the subject. Is there any standard/better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

This indeed appears to be a tricky question for shell programs! Section 2.12 "[Shell Execution Environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12)" of the POSIX-2008 standard for the "[Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)" specifies the following (emphasis mine):

> A subshell environment shall be created as a duplicate of the shell environment, **except that signal traps that are not being ignored shall be set to the default action**. Changes made to the subshell environment shall not affect the shell environment. Command substitution, commands that are grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous lists shall be executed in a subshell environment.

In other words, everything barring interprocess communication (for example through a named pipe) is separate between shell execution environments. This includes the trap handlers themselves, which are automatically reset to the default state upon entering a subshell (unless a trap handler was set to the ignored state).

In the example output provided in your question, note that while you sent three signals (according to your diagram), the trap handler was only called twice. This is the expected behavior because one of the signals was sent while the first trap handler was still running, which was therefore delivered to the trap handler installed in the subshell environment that the first trap handler was running in. Unless changed by the trap handler itself, this should be set to the default state, where the default state is presumably the ignored state for the particular signal you used in your example.

Both of your solutions, grouping commands with parentheses and command substitution, create a subshell environment that resets the trap handler before any commands are run in order to ensure that it is not called again if another signal is sent. The difference as you note is that using a command substitution allows the trap handler to affect the state of the parent shell execution environment, while simply grouping commands does not provide a convenient means to do so.

> However, the whole issue appears to be linux-specific: bash on Mac OS doesn't interrupt handlers at all. That makes my solution rely on undocumented behavior to overcome undocumented platform-specific behavior. That doesn't sound to be reliable.

As established, the solutions you proposed are fully specified by POSIX. What may be unspecified is whether or not a trap handler is called when a trap handler is already running, and according to your testing Mac OS and Linux differ. Nothing in the standard that I have found says that a trap handler should not be called again as would be done and as is standardized in C, which suggests to me that the Linux behavior is to be expected. On the other hand, nothing in the standard would seem to prevent the shell from blocking signals while a trap handler is being run either, and this could be a useful convention if it could be relied upon.

An alternative approach would be to simply reset the trap handler to the default state in the trap handler itself using the `trap` builtin as follows:

```bash
handler() {
    trap - USR1
    # run handler
    trap handler USR1
}

trap handler USR1
# run program
```

This may be more convenient in that all of the state change required by the trap handler does not have to be passed through to the parent shell execution environment through a single variable. Instead, the full parent shell execution environment may be changed as per normal.